# how to put char at multiple indices

Tags: java, arraylist, stringbuilder, charat

`i have to think a 12 letter word and the computer has to guess the word.` i have an arraylist of letters A to Z.  i let the computer randomly pick a letter and i have to put the letter at an index if the letter is in the word. but what if the letter has to go at index 2 and 8. `how could i do that?` 
 a hint would be very helpfull.

!! if the computer guesses a letter in the word i set that letter at the corresponding index i type  2 for example

right know it puts the letter only at one index then removes the letter(because it can gues that letter only one time.  i'm using a 12 letter word.

```
            private Scanner sc;
            private ArrayList<Character> letters;
            private int answer;
            private char randL;
            private char ch;
            private int wrongG = 0; 
            private int wrongA = 0; 
            private int randNum;
            private StringBuilder hiddenW = new StringBuilder("............");
            private boolean match;

  public void gameComputer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { 
        ch = (char) ('A' + i);
        letters.add(ch);
    }

    while (wrongA < 10) {
        randNum = (int) (Math.random() * letters.size());
        randL = letters.get(randNum);
        System.out.println("De computer raadt een " + randL
                + ". Op welke plaats(en) staat die letter?");
        answer = sc.nextInt();

        for (int ii = 0; ii < hiddenW.length(); ii++) {
            if (answer > -1 && answer < 12) {
                hiddenW.setCharAt(answer, randL);
                match = true;

            }

        }

        if (answer == 100) {
            match = false;
        }
        if (match) {
            System.out.println(hiddenW);
            System.out.println("Aantal fouten: " + wrongA);
        }
        if (!match) {
            wrongA = wrongA + 1;
            System.out.println("Aantal fouten: " + wrongA);
        }
        if (wrongA == 10) {
            System.out.println("you couldn't guess the word");
            break;
        }
        letters.remove(randNum);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 the computer guessed O. Op welke plaats(en) staat die letter?
 2 8     
..O.........
Aantal fouten: 0
the computer guessed  I. Op welke plaats(en) staat die letter?
..O.....I...
Aantal fouten: 0
the computer guessed  K. Op welke plaats(en) staat die letter?
```

i would like to put the letter at multiple indices 
like if the computer guessed an `A` 
i would like to type 2 and 8 and set the `letter A` at indices 2 and 8

Comment: Could you give an example, rather than an explanation, of what should happen? I'm not fully understanding, and an example will (hopefully) help.

Comment: if the computer guessed the Letter A i would like to type 2 and 8 and it sets the letter A at indices 2 and 8 know it only set the letter only onces  at index 2. @CoderMusgrove

Comment: Your code seems incredibly weird. You have `while(wrongG < 10)` and you never use `wrongG` anywhere else in your code. Later down in the code you have `wrongA` which isn't used anywhere else either. Also you say that the user guesses a letter, but I only see `sc.nextInt()` in your code. An integer is not a letter. The random number `randL` doesn't make much sense to me either. It is really hard understanding what you are trying to do. One would think that this is a hangman-game, but your code suggests otherwise. Clarify, please.

Comment: the computer guesses a letter, form the letters in the letter arrayList. let me edit @Gendarme

Comment: it kinda hangman but i have to think of the word and the computer guesses a letter an i have to put that letter at a corresponding index if its in the word. @Gendarme

Answer (score 0):

The function toCharArray() should help.

Im thinking you could decompose the hidden word with toCharArray then compare the randomly chosen letter to each of the members of the new array.

[toCHarArray()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_tochararray.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to give several indices instead of one, use `sc.nextLine()` instead of `sc.nextInt()` and write the indices separated by a comma (or something else if you despise commas) - for example "2,8". Then you can read the whole string by using `charAt` and iterating through the whole string or any other way you like.